# Cómo hacer insert mediante un botón en oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, apex

Tengo este problema:
Tengo un interactive grid llamado Pedidos_clientes, con las columnas IDPRODUCTO, PRODUCTO, precio y en stock (obtenidas de una tabla llamada productos), además de 3 columnas más llamadas cantidad, idcuenta (obtiene la información de un shared component) y ordenar (que es un link) que activa una función dinámica.

La idea es que al presionar el link "ordenar", se envíe a la tabla detallescuenta el idcuenta, el idproducto  y que la cantidad de registros sean los indicados en cantidad. Pero no lo hace, la tabla detallescuenta me aparece sin registros

[image: Parte visual]

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

Selecciono la cuenta id:22 y presiono el link de ordenar del producto id:41 y en cantidad digito 5

Resultado: Se inserta 5 veces el registro del producto id:41 a la cuenta id:22

No sé si me explico. Estoy anuente a cambios o recomendaciones, puesto que no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo. Muchas gracias